# Derivation convolution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose a random vector $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ has a spherically symmetric distribution with density of the form $f(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$. Denote by $Z=X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2$ then the random variable $Y=X_1^2+X_2^2$ has density $g$ of the form:

$$g(y) = \int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{z-y}} f(z) dz $$

Can anyone help with the derivation of this result? I tried using polar coordinates but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution:
$$(u, y, z) = \left(\frac{x^2_1}{x_1^2 + x_2^2}, x_1^2 + x_2^2, x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\right)$$

It inverse is: $$\left(x_1, x_2, x_3\right) = \left(\sqrt{uy}, \sqrt{y(1-u)}, \sqrt{z-y}\right)$$

with jacobian:

$$J(u, y, z) = \left|\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\sqrt{y} & \frac1{2\sqrt{y}}\sqrt{u} & 0\\
-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-u}}\sqrt{y} & \frac1{2\sqrt{y}}\sqrt{1-u} & 0\\
0 & -\frac1{2\sqrt{z-y}} & \frac1{2\sqrt{z-y}}\\
\end{matrix}\right| = \frac1{8\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}\sqrt{z-y}}$$

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\varphi(Y)\right] &= \int_{x\in \mathbb R^3} \varphi\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2\right) f\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\right)\mathrm dx\\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2\right) f\left(x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2\right)\mathrm dx_3\mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_1\\
&= 8\int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi(y) \int_{y}^{\infty}f(z) \int_{0}^{1} \left|\frac1{8\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}\sqrt{z-y}}\right| \mathrm du\mathrm dz\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi(y) \left(\int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{f(z)}{\sqrt{z-y}}\mathrm dz\right)\left(\int_{0}^{1} \frac1{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-u}} \mathrm d u\right)
\end{align}